# how to pass dynamic variable to XML in Spring Batch

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, spring-batch

I have written following query in XML File & want to pass dynamic value for created_date from java code, I am creating spring batch program. So how to do it?

```
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="sql"
        value="SELECT `txn`.`id`,
                    `txn`.`sender_id`,
                    `txn`.`beneficiary_id`,
                    `txn`.`amount`,
                    `txn`.`pay_mode_master_id`,
                    `txn`.`status`,
                    `txn`.`reference_number`,
                    `txn`.`created_by`,
                    `txn`.`created_date`,
                    `txn`.`updated_by`,
                    `txn`.`updated_date`,
                    `txn`.`source_currency_master_id`,
                    `txn`.`dest_currency_master_id`,
                    `txn`.`fees`,
                    `txn`.`exchange_rate`,
                    `txn`.`total_amount`,
                    `txn`.`recipient_gets`,
                    `txn`.`from_country`,
                    `txn`.`to_country`,
                    `txn`.`other_purpose`,
                    `txn`.`transaction_purpose_id`,
                    `txn`.`sender_account_id`,
                    `txn`.`transaction_number`,
                    `txn`.`source_region`,
                    `txn`.`error`,
                    `txn`.`corridor_id`,
                    `txn`.`promo_code`,
                    `txn`.`receiver_id`,
                    `txn`.`error_code`
                FROM `remittance`.`transaction_master` txn where txn.created_date >= '2017-02-09 00:00:00' AND txn.created_date <='2017-02-09 23:59:59';" />

    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing your query in `xml` file, so I consider this you can parse and fetch the original query string. After that you can simply pass the dynamic value from the java code in the following way.

**Code:**

```
List<Date> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
/* Here add all dates to the parameter ArrayList */
String query = "SELECT `txn`.`id`,
                    `txn`.`sender_id`,
                    `txn`.`beneficiary_id`,
                    `txn`.`amount`,
                    `txn`.`pay_mode_master_id`,
                    `txn`.`status`,
                    `txn`.`reference_number`,
                    `txn`.`created_by`,
                    `txn`.`created_date`,
                    `txn`.`updated_by`,
                    `txn`.`updated_date`,
                    `txn`.`source_currency_master_id`,
                    `txn`.`dest_currency_master_id`,
                    `txn`.`fees`,
                    `txn`.`exchange_rate`,
                    `txn`.`total_amount`,
                    `txn`.`recipient_gets`,
                    `txn`.`from_country`,
                    `txn`.`to_country`,
                    `txn`.`other_purpose`,
                    `txn`.`transaction_purpose_id`,
                    `txn`.`sender_account_id`,
                    `txn`.`transaction_number`,
                    `txn`.`source_region`,
                    `txn`.`error`,
                    `txn`.`corridor_id`,
                    `txn`.`promo_code`,
                    `txn`.`receiver_id`,
                    `txn`.`error_code`
                FROM `remittance`.`transaction_master` txn where txn.created_date >= :created_date AND txn.created_date <=:created_date";
/* call addDynamicDateToQuery using the class object in which your 
addDynamicDateToQuery method is present */
query = addDynamicDateToQuery(query ,"created_date",parameters);

public static String addDynamicDateToQuery(String query, String token,
            Collection data) {
        if(data.isEmpty() || !query.contains(":")){
            query = null;
        }else{
            StringBuffer clause = new StringBuffer("");
            for(Object value : data){
                if(value instanceof Date){
                    clause.append(value + ",");
                }
            }
            String clauseStr = clause.toString();
            clauseStr = clauseStr.substring(0,clauseStr.lastIndexOf(","));
            query = query.replace(":" + token, clauseStr);
        }
        return query;
    }

/* Now You can call this query using JdbcTemplate object */
```

Comment: but I want to put the whole query in XML, but the parameter should be passed dynamically from java code  & want to use that query for spring batch job.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, following is the code change I needed to do in the java file from where I am calling the job..

```
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("createdDate", "'%2017-02-24%'").toJobParameters();
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
```

---

& in the xml file...

    
        
        
                    FROM `remittance`.`transaction_master` txn where txn.created_date like #{jobParameters['createdDate']};" />

And you must put scope="step" in to bean tag. Otherwise it will give error.

You can put multiple parameter like:

```
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("targetPath", targetPath).addString("sourceFile", sourceFile).toJobParameters();
```